# Doctrine resultCache breaks entity removal

Tags: orm, doctrine

I'm having trouble using the Doctrine ORM's result cache. The app manages creating/deleting channel entities and adding data to channels for monitoring purposes via a JSON REST interface. Caching the channel entities across requests is desirable for performance reasons as they are mostly static.

During unit testing we've found problems with the flow 1) create channel 2) add data and 3) delete channel. A new entity manager is used in the code below to simulate the separate JSON requests for testing purposes:

```
public function run() {
    // 1) add channel
    $this->em = self::createEntityManager();
    $channel = new Model\Channel('power');
    echo($uuid = $channel->getUuid());

    $this->setProperties($channel, array('title'=>'Meter', 'resolution'=>100));

    $this->em->persist($channel);
    $this->em->flush();
    $this->clearCache();

    // 2) add data
    $this->em = self::createEntityManager();
    $channel = $this->get($uuid);
    $this->dumpEntityState($channel, 'add ');

    $channel->addData(new Model\Data($channel, 1000000, 1));
    $this->em->flush();
    $this->dumpEntityState($channel, 'adddata ');

    // this fixes the problem
    // $this->clearCache();

    // 3) delete channel
    $this->em = self::createEntityManager();
    $entity = $this->get($uuid);
    $this->dumpEntityState($channel, 'delete ');

    if ($entity instanceof Model\Channel) {
        $entity->clearData($this->em);
    }

    $this->em->remove($entity);
    $this->em->flush();
    $this->clearCache();
}
```

The channel entity is retrieved by its identifier:

```
public function get($uuid) {
    if (!Util\UUID::validate($uuid)) {
        throw new \Exception('Invalid UUID: \'' . $uuid . '\'');
    }

    $dql = 'SELECT a, p
        FROM Volkszaehler\Model\Entity a
        LEFT JOIN a.properties p
        WHERE a.uuid = :uuid';

    $q = $this->em->createQuery($dql);
    $q->setParameter('uuid', $uuid);

    // this breaks the app
    $q->useResultCache(true);

    try {
        return $q->getSingleResult();
    } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
        throw new \Exception('No entity found with UUID: \'' . $uuid . '\'', 404);
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that once `useResultCache(true)` is used, deleting the entity in step 3) results in error:

```
Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'A detached entity can not be removed.' in \ORM\UnitOfWork.php
```

As soon as `useResultCache()` is `false`, the problem is gone.

How can the resultCache influence the removal of entities, especially as the result cache is cleared whenever the channel entity is updated?

**UPDATE**

Checking the channel entity state after adding data on a freshly retrieved entity from the existing entity manager, it's state is already DETACHED. This is also the first time the result cache comes into play.

How/why does result cache make entities DETACHED?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is found with Doctrine: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-446 cached entities are always "detached". If you need a managed entity you can merge it- though at a cost of an additional DB query.

**Conclusion**

If managed entities are needed for removal etc. it's best to not use cached query results.

**Update**

This behaviour has been changed in Doctrine 2.3- cached results are now always hydrated and therefore become managed.